# long term effects of TB

Tags: research, back, lasting-effects-duration, tuberculosis, lumbago-low-back-pain

I contracted and suffered from TB when I was 3 years old and apparently it was an acute case because as my mother said they feared for my life. The disease was cured and I have had no sequels or long term effects that I know of, leading an active life, doing sports, yoga and so on.
Now in my fifties I'm beginning to have issues of backpain. The medical tests put it down to ageing but (now the question) could it be long-term effects of 
the childhood TB?
Lastly, as I have some training as a paramedic, could you direct me to some bibliography?
Thank you